# How to implement onTouchListener to an item of listview without effecting scrolling

Tags: android, listview, ontouchlistener, custom-adapter

I have a list View in my Main Activity, which contains a list of full size images. i am trying to implement onTouchListener on that image view of list view to get the points where user touched. and i am getting it correct by implementing onTouchListener in get View method of Custom Adapter for list view. but when i touch screen for scrolling list it still gives me the points while scrolling the list. but i don't want to get onTouchListener called while scrolling the list. How can i do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may try this, this might work

```
    float posX, posY;
    imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            posX = event.getX();
            posY = event.getY();
        }
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            if (((posX >= event.getX() && posX <= event.getX() + 10) || (posX <= event
                        .getX() && posX >= event.getX() - 10))
                        && ((posY >= event.getY() && posY <= event.getY() + 10) || (posY <= event
                                .getY() && posY >= event.getY() - 10))){
                //Do your thing
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    });
```

Comment: i tried this. it make onScroll working fine, but without scrolling when i touch the screen it sometimes displays points and sometimes not.

Comment: that was a fault of my device, tested on emulator. this solution worked perfectly for my case. Thank u so much. voted up and marked as answer as well.

Comment: sorry my logic went completely wrong with previous edit

Comment: ACTION_UP and ACTION_DOWN events doesn't happen at same position every time so this was the reason it was working occasionally with previous code but I changed the condition logic so that it only returns true if ACTION_DOWN position lies within 10 units of ACTION _UP event in x and y direction when it lies beyond 10 units i.e. while scrolling to goes beyond 10 units it returns false.

Comment: if (Math.abs((posY - event.getY())) < 10) { }i tried this as inner condition, and it is working.

Answer (score 0):

I think the proper way to do this is by implementing `onClickListener` instead of `onTouchListener`.

And yes, the very reason is because the `View` will be touched when the user only intent to scroll the `ListView`.

Answer (score 0):

override this method and done with respect to your requirement.

```
@Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

        if (isScrooling) {
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: where do i add this override method?

Comment: write a class which extends ListView and override the methods and place setter and getter for isScrooling and handle it.

Comment: write CustomListiew class extends ListView and override this method, and place this CustomListiew in your xml layout.